# How do I load files/directories into MobaxTerm to start a Tractor (for genetics) operation?

Tags: genetics, mobaxterm, gwas

Tractor is an operation that adds power to GWAS for an admixed individual. There are online tutorials, but I am struggling to even start running Tractor in MobaXTerm. Every time I try to run some of the code I get back "cant open file - *whatever file* - no such file or directory". I do not know how to implement the  correct files needed to run the operation and have tried downloading files and opening in the MobaXTerm app. Do I need to create a whole separate directory? I am pretty new to using Moba and don't really know where to start with Tractor.

Comment: It is not very clear from your question what you re trying to do. Could you share the link of online tutorials?

Comment: https://github.com/Atkinson-Lab/Tractor-tutorial/blob/main/Rfmix.md    <This is the tutorial for the program. I ended up needing to create a directory and uploading the files individually to be able to start the tutorial.

Comment: You also need to paste the output of your terminal here. Without looking at your commands it is difficult to comments.